# PixiJS - Sprite not being rendered on screen

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

This is my first time using PixiJS and I'm following the tutorial

https://pixijs.io/guides/basics/getting-started.html

To try and get an image rendered onto the screen.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://pixijs.download/release/pixi.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      // Create the application helper and add its render target to the page
      let app = new PIXI.Application({ width: 640, height: 360 });
      document.body.appendChild(app.view);

      // Create the sprite and add it to the stage
      let sprite = PIXI.Sprite.from('sample.png');
      app.stage.addChild(sprite);

      // Add a ticker callback to move the sprite back and forth
      let elapsed = 0.0;
      app.ticker.add((delta) => {
        elapsed += delta;
        sprite.x = 100.0 + Math.cos(elapsed/50.0) * 100.0;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm using the exact code provided inside the tutorial, but I can't get anything to appear.

[image]

The `path` of `sample.png` is in the same directory as my html file.

[image]

What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: How are you serving your files? Webpack? Vite? Something else? Some of these expect you to place the statics into a `public` folder or similar.

Comment: @EduardoPáezRubio I'm trying to deploy it as a frontend only application with Chrome Extensions. I am simply opening the .html file right now and it's not being rendered.

Comment: Can you try `let sprite = PIXI.Sprite.from(chrome.runtime.getURL('sample.png'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app seems to work, since the black frame is appearing. The sprite is the only thing not appearing. I tried copying the code and it works for me with my own image:

[image: working example]
Running your project by opening the index.html file won't work because it can't reach the sample.png file. You need a development build to do that. I recommend using the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) VSCode extension to test your project.

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah I was running the project by just running the index.html.